# scikit learn extratreeclassifier hanging

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm running the scikit learn on some rather large training datasets ~1,600,000,000 rows with ~500 features.  The platform is Ubuntu server 14.04, the hardware has 100gb of ram and 20 CPU cores.

The test datasets are about half as many rows.

I set n_jobs = 10, and am forest_size = 3*number_of_features so about 1700 trees.

If I reduce the number of features to about 350 it works fine but never completes the training phase with the full feature set of 500+.  The process is still executing and using up about 20gb of ram but is using 0% of CPU.  I have also successfully completed on datasets with ~400,000 rows but twice as many features which completes after only about 1 hour.

I am being careful to delete any arrays/objects that are not in use.

Does anyone have any ideas I might try?

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? Have you tried with the current master branch of the project?

Comment: Here is an update, after a restart I made it through training but now it is hanging during the prediction phase, there are 47 rcuos processes running as root.

Comment: I killed all the script processes running scikit, the 47 rcous processes remain until I reboot the server.

Comment: You should try with the current master of scikit-learn. RandomForestClassifier is now using Python threads (a single python process). It should be more robust to highly concurrent workloads.

Comment: I installed the latest master branch (committed 2hrs ago as I'm writing this) I get an error message that ends with:    from ..utils.sparsefuncs import inplace_column_scale
ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale

Answer (score 1):

Installing the current master branch version as suggested by [orgrisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163740/ogrisel) worked for me.  I did have to a "make clean" as described [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3046).

The new version seems to be a really big improvement.  I hope it is released soon.

Many thanks to orgisel and other contributors for such a great piece of software!